# Copying problem after deleting item from recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

after deleting the picture from recyclerview, it creates a copy of the other pictures in the list

```
galleryAdapter.setOnLongClickListiner(new GalleryAdapter.OnItemLongClickListiner() {
            @Override
            public void onItemLongClick(Gallery gallery, int position) {
               
                DocumentReference documentReference=firebaseFirestore.collection("Gallery").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).collection("myGallery").document(galleryModelArrayList.get(position).docId);
                documentReference.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            galleryModelArrayList.remove(galleryModelArrayList.get(position));
                            galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),R.string.gallerySilindi,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"ERROR:"+task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                 


            }
        });
```

I download the pictures this way and save them to a list, this way I show the pictures with the recyclerview, is there a problem here?

```
 public  void  getData() {

           firebaseFirestore.collection("Gallery").document(firebaseUser.getUid()).collection("myGallery").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    if (value != null) {
                        for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : value.getDocuments()) {
                            Map<String, Object> data = snapshot.getData();
                            String downloadUrl = (String) data.get("downloadUrl");
                            String docId = (String) data.get("docId");
                            String ımagaId = (String) data.get("imageId");
                           // checkBox=findViewById(R.id.checkimages);
                                GalleryModel galleryModel=new GalleryModel(docId,downloadUrl,checkBox,ımagaId);
                            galleryModelArrayList.add(galleryModel);

                        }
                        galleryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

[image][image]

Comment: How do you read the pictures from the database?

Comment: Can you check how I added the pictures?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: ı dont understand yoır say please can you explain